# Sorting a Calculated datasource in AppMaker

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a Calculated datasource that's populated via an appscript function. When I display this datasource in a table, it works great but I can't click on the headers to sort them. I'd like to implement sorting.

I can see that sorting is specified in the [Query](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/server#Query) object using `Query.sorting.<fieldname>._ascending()` and `descending()`. What I can't figure out is how to read the value that was set by these functions so I can determine how the user wants me to sort the results.

How do I determine what the desired sort is from the appmaker Query object?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any documentation around this either, but by inspecting the Query object, I found I can do this:

- query.sorting.._order: true - ascending; false - descending; null - no sorting by this column.
- query.sorting.._priority: 0 based priority, null - no sorting.

So assuming I have a "Title" column, by inspecting query.sorting.Title._order and query.sorting.Title._priority, I can tell if I should or how to sort by it.